# Listing all not null constraints in a postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, constraints, psql

I am trying to use psql in the terminal to find all nullable columns in a database. If I use

```
select * from information_schema.check_constraints;
```

I get information such as the following

```
 constraint_catalog | constraint_schema  |       constraint_name        |                                         check_clause                                         
--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 foo                | public             | 12345_67890_1_not_null       | bar IS NOT NULL
```

Unfortunately, the column `bar` appears in many tables. What is the easist way I can get a list of all `public` constraints like this which list both the column names and the table names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the list of `NOT NULL` columns in a particular table, you can do:

```sql
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE is_nullable = 'NO';
```

From here, you can remove the constraints by iterating over the results of this query in a scripting language of your choice and doing:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "schema_name"."table_name" ALTER "column_name" DROP NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to check the `is_nullable` from the `columns` view.